# Yet Another Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been populating my git with some old code, and I came across this linked list I wrote about 10-12 months ago. I'm wondering just how thread safe it is and if there are any improvements I can make in terms of optimization. It uses a re-entrant pthread mutex and it looks as if they are locked when altering any critical sections, and I haven't come across any memory leaks, so I'm curious as to how well it will stand up to scrutiny.

An example usage (does not currently allow multiple types of lists since the type is provided via a PP definition):

https://github.com/GoodiesHQ/List/blob/master/main.c

### list.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef LIST_TYPE
#define LIST_TYPE int
#endif
typedef LIST_TYPE val;

typedef enum _status status;
typedef struct _list list, *plist;
typedef struct _node node, *pnode;
typedef val(*list_func)(val v1, val v2);

enum _status
{
    SUCCESS,
    MEMORY_FAILURE,
    OUT_OF_BOUNDS,
    FAILURE,
};

struct _list
{
    pnode head;
    pnode tail;
    size_t size;
    pthread_mutex_t mu;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mu_attr;
};

struct _node
{
    plist owner;
    pnode next;
    pnode prev;
    val value;
};

typedef void (*callback_t)(val);

#define LIST_LOCK(l) pthread_mutex_lock(&((l)->mu))
#define LIST_UNLOCK(l) pthread_mutex_unlock(&((l)->mu))
#define LIST_INC_SIZE(l) (l)->size++
#define LIST_DEC_SIZE(l) (l)->size--
#define LIST_DESTROY_MUTEX(l) pthread_mutex_destroy(&((l)->mu))

// initialization and deconstruction of a list
void list_print_status(status);
plist list_new(void);
plist list_copy(plist);
pnode node_new(val value);
void list_init(plist l);
void list_del(plist *l);

// getting an item from a list
status list_get_val(plist l, size_t index, val *value);
status list_get_ptr(plist l, size_t index, val **value);
status list_get_node(plist l, size_t index, pnode *n);
status list_swap(plist l, size_t index1, size_t index2);
status list_reverse(plist l);

// display the list
void list_print(plist l, const char* val_fmt);
void list_print_reverse(plist l, const char* val_fmt);

// iterating the list
pnode list_iter(plist l);
bool list_iter_next(pnode *n);
void list_map(callback_t callback, plist l);

// adding elements to a list
status list_append(plist l, val value);
status list_prepend(plist l, val value);
status list_insert_at(plist l, size_t index, val Value);

// removing elements from a list
status list_remove_back(plist l);
status list_remove_font(plist l);
status list_remove_at(plist l, size_t index);
#endif
```

### list.c

```
#include "list.h"

static const char *val_fmt = "%d";

void list_print_status(status s){
    switch(s)
    {
        case SUCCESS:
            // Upon success, print nothing.
            //fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");
            break;
        case MEMORY_FAILURE:
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory.\n");
            break;
        case OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            fprintf(stderr, "The index provided does not exist.\n");
            break;
        case FAILURE:
            fprintf(stderr, "An unspecified error has occurred.\n");
            break;
    }
}

plist list_new(void)
{
    plist new_list = malloc(sizeof(*new_list));
    if(!new_list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    list_init(new_list);
    return new_list;
}

plist list_copy(plist p)
{
    plist lst = list_new();
    pnode it = p->head;
    while(it != NULL)
    {
        if(list_append(lst, it->value) != SUCCESS)
        {
            list_del(&lst);
            return NULL;
        }
        it = it->next;
    }
    return lst;
}

// construct a new node based on the provided value
pnode node_new(val value)
{
    pnode new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    if(!new_node)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_node->next=NULL;
    new_node->prev=NULL;
    new_node->value = value;

    return new_node;
}

// initialize a list's objects to NULL and initializes the mutex
void list_init(plist l)
{
    l->head=NULL;
    l->tail=NULL;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&l->mu_attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&l->mu_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&l->mu, &l->mu_attr);
}

// free a list and delete the 
void list_del(plist *l)
{
    LIST_LOCK(*l);

    pnode n = (*l)->head;
    pnode tmp = NULL;

    while(n != NULL)
    {
        tmp = n->next;
        free(n);
        n = tmp;
    }

    LIST_UNLOCK(*l);
    LIST_DESTROY_MUTEX(*l);
    free(*l);
    *l = NULL;
}

// store value of l[index] inside the provided pointer
status list_get_val(plist l, size_t index, val *value)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    pnode n = NULL;
    status s = list_get_node(l, index, &n);
    if(s != SUCCESS)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return s;
    }
    *value = n->value;
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}

// store the pointer to the value inside the provided pointer
status list_get_ptr(plist l, size_t index, val **value)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    pnode n = NULL;
    status s = list_get_node(l, index, &n);
    if(s != SUCCESS)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return s;
    }
    *value = &n->value;
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}


// store a pointer to the node inside the provided pointer
status list_get_node(plist l, size_t index, pnode *n)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    if(index >= l->size)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
    }
    pnode it = l->head;
    while(index--)
    {
        it = it->next;
    }

    *n = it;

    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}

// swap two nodes at the provided indecies
status list_swap(plist l, size_t index1, size_t index2){
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    pnode n1 = NULL, n2 = NULL;
    val tmp;
    status s;

    if(
        (s = list_get_node(l, index1, &n1) != SUCCESS) ||
        (s = list_get_node(l, index2, &n2) != SUCCESS)
    )
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return s;
    }
    tmp = n2->value;
    n2->value = n1->value;
    n1->value = tmp;

    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}

status list_reverse(plist l)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    size_t size = l->size;
    if(size <= 1)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    size_t mid = size / 2;
    status s;

    for(size_t ctr = 0; ctr < mid; ++ctr)
    {
        if((s=list_swap(l, ctr, size-ctr-1)) != SUCCESS)
        {
            LIST_UNLOCK(l);
            return s;
        }
    }

    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}

void list_print(plist l, const char* val_fmt)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    if(l->size == 0)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return;
    }
    pnode n = l->head;
    while(n != NULL)
    {
        printf(val_fmt, n->value);
        n = n->next;
    }
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
}

void list_print_reverse(plist l, const char* val_fmt){
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    if(l->size == 0)
    {
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return;
    }
    pnode n = l->tail;
    while(n != NULL)
    {
        printf(val_fmt, n->value);
        n = n->prev;
    }
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
}


pnode list_iter(plist l)
{
    return l->head;
    return NULL;
}

bool list_iter_next(pnode *n)
{
    pnode nd = *n;
    *n = nd->next;
    return *n != NULL;
}

void list_map(callback_t callback, plist l)
{
    LIST_LOCK(l);
    pnode it = list_iter(l);
    if(it)
    {
        do
        {
            callback(it->value);
        } while(list_iter_next(&it));
    }
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
}

status list_append(plist l, val value)
{
    pnode n = node_new(value);
    if(!n)
    {
        return MEMORY_FAILURE;
    }

    n->owner = l;

    LIST_LOCK(l);
    LIST_INC_SIZE(l);

    if(l->head == NULL || l->tail == NULL)
    {
        assert(l->head == NULL && l->tail == NULL); // they should never be either/or
        l->head = l->tail = n;
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    assert(l->tail->next == NULL);
    n->prev = l->tail;
    l->tail->next = n;
    l->tail = n;
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}

status list_prepend(plist l, val value){
    pnode n = node_new(value);
    if(!n)
    {
        return MEMORY_FAILURE;
    }

    n->owner = l;

    LIST_LOCK(l);
    LIST_INC_SIZE(l);

    if(l->head == NULL || l->tail == NULL)
    {
        assert(l->head == NULL && l->tail == NULL); // they should never be either/or
        l->head = l->tail = n;
        LIST_UNLOCK(l);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    assert(l->head->prev == NULL);
    n->next = l->head;
    l->head->prev = n;
    l->head = n;
    LIST_UNLOCK(l);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Consider `default:` instead of `case FAILURE:` as an surprising `status` is also _An unspecified error_.

Comment: One thing I've already fixed is using `calloc` as opposed to `malloc` for the allocation as sometimes the sizes were initialized to non-zero values and it was causing a segfault when reversing the list since the sizes were not accurate.